# Deploying a Flask app that runs Jar files online

Tags: api, rest, flask, deployment

I would like to deploy an API written in Python using Flask. The problem is that some requests execute a jar file that generates code, which is then returned to the user. I tried using pythonanywhere, but the problem is that it will not allow me to execute jar files. I would appreciate some indications as to where I can deploy such an app, with instructions on how to do so.

Comment: What kind of errors were you getting on PythonAnywhere?